# Registry OpenSubkey returns null, although it is there

Tags: c#, registry, vsto, outlook-addin

I have read almost all the other questions to this topic, but they usually resolved by using the wrong architecture view in the registry.

I am trying to open a subkey in "...\Outlook\Addins". I have the subkey available for both architectures ( "HKLM\Software... " and "HKLM\Software\Wow3264Node..."
). But  I know through testing, that the code is looking under "WOW6432Node".

So here is the code snippet.

```
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Default);
var reg = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddin", false);
```

I also tried

```
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Registry32);
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Registry64);
```

to debug it and looked for the subkeys, that are visible, which give me all other entries (even newly created ones), but not the one I am looking for.

I also checked Registry Permissions, which are the same as for the others I can see.

So why do I receive always null for "reg"?

Edit: Maybe I should add, that I am looking for that key from inside the addin. When trying it from a short test console application, I see the subkey when calling

```
reg.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Comment: thank you Gerald, for adding the Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, this is a security "feature". There is no way of accessing the registry branch of the addin, which is looking for it. 
The information, which I would like to have stored there, needed to be stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Default);
```

to this

```
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Registry64);
```

When you run a 32-bits application on a 64-bits OS it tries to find the `Wow6432Node` automatically.
Another way around it probably is to compile it for the x64 architecture.

More info on the RegistryView enumeration can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx).
Note this line;

> If you request a 64-bit view on a 32-bit operating system, the returned keys will be in the 32-bit view.

So you should be safe always requesting the 64-bits keys.

Comment: Already tried that, thats why I was writing a new question. The Subkey is available in "HKLM\Software\... " and "HKLM\Software\Wow3264Node\..."

So either way, it should be visible, which it is, in a short console application, where i did copy and paste, but not from inside the addin itself.

I edited the question, to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This was doing my head in for about 4 hours until I realised I had forgotten to uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" under Project > Software Properties...

Comment: As stated in the question, that was not it.